# Need help solving an equation: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\ln{x}-2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve this equation:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\ln{x}-2=0$$
What I noticed was that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln{x}=\frac{1}{x}$. Don't know how this would help.

Comment: Is this a part of some course you are taking? Because at first sight I would solve it numerically.

Comment: There is no nice closed form (unless perhaps you use special functions). If you wish to approximate, consider Newton's method.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 How would one I use Newton's method here?

Comment: @T_M Yes, I am allowed to solve it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably not get any nice closed form -- [because there does not seem to be any.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1%2Fx+%2B+ln+x+-+2+%3D0&t=crmtb01) *But* you can prove that there are only two real solutions (and then approximate them numerically, e.g. with Newton's method, with a computer, or by hand).

Consider your function $f\colon x\in(0,\infty)\mapsto \frac{1}{x}+\ln x -2$. It  is a smooth function, and 
$$
f^\prime(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)
$$
cancels at only one point, $x=1$, and is negative (resp. positive) before (resp. after). Hence $f$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$ and increasing on $(1,\infty)$.

Since $f\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{} \infty$, $f(1)=-1 < 0$ and $f\xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} \infty$, the Intermediate Value Theorem guarantees $f$ cancels at least once in $(0,1)$ and once in $(1,\infty)$. Monotononicity guarantees these are the only two roots.

---

For instance, as $f(\frac{1}{2}) = -\ln 2 < 0$, you know that the first root, $r_1$, is in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$. 
Refining, you have $f(e^{-2}) = e^2-4 = (e-2)(e+2) > 0$ and $f(e^{-1}) = e-3 < 0$, so $r_1\in(e^{-2},e^{-1})$.

On the other hand, $f(e^2) = \frac{1}{e^2} > 0$ and $f(e) = \frac{1}{e}-1 < 0$, so you also know that the second root $r_2$ is in $(e,e^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a 'sort' of closed form using the Lambert W function.

$$\frac1x+\ln(x)=2$$

$$e^{\frac1x+\ln(x)}=e^2$$

$$e^{\frac1x}e^{\ln(x)}=e^2$$

$$xe^{\frac1x}=e^2$$

Power both sides by $-1$.

$$\frac1xe^{-\frac1x}=e^{-2}$$

Multiply by $-1$.

$$-\frac1xe^{-\frac1x}=-e^{-2}$$

Take the "W" of both sides.

$$-\frac1x=W(-e^{-2})$$

Solve for $x$.

$$x=\frac{-1}{W(-e^{-2})}$$

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20ye%5Ey%3De%5E-2&t=crmtb01) confirms. (use $y=-x^{-1}$)